# Какая разница между этими двумя способами создания экземпляра класса?

Tags: java

Предположим, у нас есть два класса.

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
```

Какая разница между

```
B b = new B();
```

и

```
A b = new B();
```

?

Comment: Доступны только те поля и методы, которые указаны в типе.
То есть в случае с A b = new B(); новые свойства, определенные только в классе B будут недоступны для обращения к ним.

Answer (score 3):

В первом случае вы сможете использовать все методы и свойства B используя переменную b. Во втором случае, хоть и объект у Вас является экземпляром класса B, использовать вы сможете только методы и свойства, доступные в классе А. Ну и конечно в рантайме b.getClass() == a.getClass() == B.class => true.